# CSS max-height not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

This part of CSS works in all modern browsers except IE 11...   even IE 9 works. Any workarounds? I am not looking for a JavaScript fix

less

```
.div{
    max-height: calc(~'100% - 36px');
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

compiled css

```
.div{max-height:calc(100% - 2.5em);overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}
```

Comment: By the `~''` syntax I assume you're using Less? Mind posting the compiled CSS?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.div{
max-height: calc('100% - 36px') !important;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: I am really surprised that this actually works. fancy IE11. The max-height property is still broken when you re-size the browser. Do u have any recommendation on that?

Comment: No it doesn't work..... It works in IE 11 for a second. then when I refresh. It just stop working. I hate IE now.

Comment: Does not work. It works for second for you because it's a rendering issue, you probably have changed the style on the inspect element of your browser, forcing the elements to re-render.